# Empty Object in doGet Java Servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, dao

I'm using a method to that get some informations from a database and return an Object with that data.
When I use this method on a Servlet doGet the Object comes empty. When I do the same thing on a main it comes properly filled with the data. Does anyone knows what am I doing wrong, please?

Prints:

[in doGet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAvBl.png)
[in main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h43Ba.png)

In doGet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
        
        Conta conta = ContaDAO.GetConta(2);
        
        double entrada = conta.getEntrada();
        request.setAttribute("entrada", entrada);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("dashboard.jsp").forward(request, response);
    
}
```

In main:

```
public static void main(String[] Args) {
    Conta conta = new Conta();
    
    
    conta = ContaDAO.GetConta(2);
    double entrada = conta.getEntrada();
    System.out.println(conta.getEntrada());
    System.out.println(entrada);
```

This is the Conta constructor model I'm using:

```
public class Conta{

//Atributos
protected int id;
protected String nomeDaConta;
protected double saldo;
protected double gasto;
protected double entrada;
/*protected ArrayList<String> categoriaDeGasto = new ArrayList<String>();
protected ArrayList<String> categoriaDeEntrada = new ArrayList<String>();*/

public Conta() {
    super();
}
```

This is the ContaDao method that I'm using:

```
public class ContaDAO {

public ContaDAO() {
    super();
}

 public static Conta GetConta(int id){

    //Connection conexao = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Conta conta = new Conta();
    Connection conexao;
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
         
        // Com o driver do Oracle já inserido pegando a variavel conexao e passando as credenciais do Oracle
        conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle.fiap.com.br:1521:ORCL", "RM552501", "270697");
        
        String sqlGetConta = "SELECT DISTINCT CD_CONTA, NR_TOTAL_ENTRADA, NR_TOTAL_SAIDA FROM T_FINEASY_CONTA WHERE CD_CONTA = ? ORDER BY CD_CONTA";
        
        ps = conexao.prepareStatement(sqlGetConta);
        ps.setInt(1, id);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        
        while(rs.next()) {
            conta.setId(rs.getInt("CD_CONTA"));
            //System.out.println(conta.getId());
            conta.setEntrada(rs.getInt("NR_TOTAL_ENTRADA"));
            //System.out.println(conta.getEntrada());
            conta.setGasto(rs.getInt("NR_TOTAL_SAIDA"));
            //System.out.println(conta.getGasto());
            
        }
        
    DBConnection.closeconexao(conexao); 
    DBConnection.closeconexaoPS(ps);
    DBConnection.closeconexaoRS(rs);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    
    return conta;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share a [mcve] containing the minimal necessary code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: The environments in which that code is running are different. How have you set them up so that this should work in both?

Comment: Please **never** do `e.printStackTrace()` and letting the code continue running as if nothing exceptional happened. (Re)throw them all so that web page loading is immediately aborted with a clear error page.

Answer (score 0):

It was a driver issue. Basically my oracle.jdbc driver was "installed" in the wrong folder structure. I had created a folder, transferred the driver file into this folder and added it to the build path.

PS: I'm working on a dynamic web project.
The correct thing to do is to transfer the driver files to the folder: 'WebContent/WEB-INF/lib' according to the file structure that I'm using.

My professor said it's an issue with the Tomcat that only sees the driver in this way.

Thanks.

Comment: Nope. It's **not** a Tomcat related issue. See abovelinked duplicate.